# Not renaming a folder/file via terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, directory, rename

```
mv "old location" "new location"

mv /home/user/my_static /home/user/static
```

= just old folder copied into new folder.

Am I missing something completely obvious?

( I am reading the Linux tutorials and had to stop because the files would not rename)

Answer (score 2):

From `mv` [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/mv.1):

```
SYNOPSIS
       mv [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST
       mv [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY

DESCRIPTION
       Rename SOURCE to DEST, or move SOURCE(s) to DIRECTORY.
```

---

If the destination (your "new location") is a directory, the source ("old location") will be moved into that directory. So, in order to rename a file/directory you have to make sure there isn't already a directory with the same new name.

Comment: I feel like a idiot.  :-(     ...........I never capitalized my 'T'      Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you didn't typo when did it, as that is command.

It may be easier on you if your in the home directory of the user to just

```
 mv my_static /home/user/static
```

Comment: yes it was a typo, I typed mv -t instead of mv -T

Comment: Strike that, reverse it (I think)